# Java Tcp socket sending extra data?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a class that will send data in java, the server requires a certain string to actually work.

I am sending the correct string, this is the connection and sending process:

```
   // CONNECT
    try {

        // GET SERVER IP
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(this.terminalIp);

        // CREATE SOCKET
        Socket hcmSocket = new Socket(serverAddr,this.terminalPort);

        PrintWriter sendingStream = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(hcmSocket.getOutputStream())), true);
        BufferedReader recivingStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hcmSocket.getInputStream()));

        // SEND REQUEST
        sendingStream.println("00 0012552 003365 004152");
```

The server rejects this even though it is correct.

When I trace the connection with wireshark I see that the hex being sent is adding on an extra `0x000a` which is a `Line Feed`.

My problem is that I don't want that to be sent, I am making sure that the string I am sending it has no extra white space at the end to create this.

This is the Hex I wan to send :`30 30 1c 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 1c 30 30 33 32 35 32 1c 30 30 34 31 32 35 31`

But what is acutally being sent is: `30 30 1c 30 30 31 31 30 30 30 1c 30 30 33 32 35 32 1c 30 30 34 31 32 35 31 0a`

Could it be the `sendingStream` that is automatically adding this in?

Comment: guess what means **ln** in `println` method's name ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't want that to be sent, I am making sure that the string I am sending it has no extra white space at the end to create this.

No, you're not.

Look at your code:

```
sendingStream.println("00 0012552 003365 004152");
```

From the docs of [`PrintWriter.println(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-):

> Prints a String and then terminates the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

That's why you're getting the line terminator - *you asked for it*.

If you don't want it, just call `print` instead of `println`. Ideally, get rid of the `PrintWriter` entirely as it will hide exceptions from you. Just use the `BufferedWriter` instead. (I'd personally specify the charset explicitly, even though I know it's reasonable to expect the default to be UTF-8 on Android...)